# How to override gradient vector calculation method for optimization algos in Keras, Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

So I am trying to modify a couple of the optimization algos in Keras, namely Adam or just SGD. So by default I'm pretty sure the way the parameter updates work is that the loss is averaged over the data points in the batch, and then a gradient vector is calculated based on this loss value. The other way to think of it is that you average the gradients with respect to the loss values for each data point in the batch. This is the calculation I want to change, and it is gonna be expensive, so I am trying to do it inside the optimized framework that uses GPU and all that.

So, for every batch, I need to calculate the gradient with respect to the loss for each data point in the batch, then instead of taking the mean of the gradients, I will do some other average or calculation. Does anyone know how I would get access to override this functionality of Adam or SGD?

After a great comment I found that there should be a way to do what I am trying to do with the `jacobian` method from `GradientTape`. However the documentation isn't so thorough, I can't figure out how it fits into the overall picture. Here I am hoping someone can help me make an adjustment to the code to use `jacobian` instead of `gradient`.

As a hello world example I am trying to simply replace the `gradient` line with some code that uses `jacobian` and produce the same output. This will illustrate how to use the `jacobian` method and the connection with the output from the `gradient` method.

Working Code

```
class CustomModel(keras.Model):
    def train_step(self, data):
        # Unpack the data. Its structure depends on your model and
        # on what you pass to `fit()`.
        x, y = data

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = self(x, training=True)  # Forward pass
            # Compute the loss value
            # (the loss function is configured in `compile()`)
            loss = self.compiled_loss(y, y_pred, regularization_losses=self.losses)

        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars) # <-- line to change
        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
        # Update metrics (includes the metric that tracks the loss)
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred)
        # Return a dict mapping metric names to current value
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, so posting a comment -- assuming you are using `GradientTape`, you can use the `jacobian` method (instead of `gradient`) to get separate gradients per batch element and then do whatever you want with them.

Comment: @xdurch0 Thanks so much, I am digging into the internal methods and I have seen the GradientTape object with `gradient`. OK I will look into Jacobian. Now looking at that method in the docs, it does give back the gradients w.r.t. each data point. Great thank you!

Comment: @xdurch0 I am wondering the exact connection between the `gradient` method and the `jacobian` method? I have posted some working code in the question, and as a first "hello world" I am trying to simply remove the line with `gradient` and replace it with some code using `jacobian`. Do you think you could help me with that? I haven't had any luck with it, I am also having trouble finding a good document stating exactly what I should expect from the output of `jacobian`.

Comment: Yes, I will post some code in an answer later.

Comment: @xdurch0 Looking more into the docs it seems the behavior I am seeing might be a consequence of returning only the mean loss from the loss function (which is default), I am reading that the loss function can actually return all losses from the data points in the batch. Using that array of losses with the gradient function might return all the gradients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do the following:

```
class CustomModel(keras.Model):
    def train_step(self, data):
        # Unpack the data. Its structure depends on your model and
        # on what you pass to `fit()`.
        x, y = data

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = self(x, training=True)  # Forward pass
            # Compute the loss value
            # (the loss function is configured in `compile()`)
            loss = self.compiled_loss(y, y_pred, regularization_losses=self.losses)

        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.jacobian(loss, trainable_vars)

        new_gradients = []
        for grad in gradients:
            new_grad = do_something_to(grad)
            new_gradients.append(new_grad)

        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(new_gradients, trainable_vars))
        # Update metrics (includes the metric that tracks the loss)
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred)
        # Return a dict mapping metric names to current value
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
```

Some important notes: `loss` returned by the `compiled_loss` function must not average over the batch axis, i.e. I'm assuming it is a tensor of shape `(batch_size, )`, *not* a scalar.
This will cause the jacobian to return gradients of the shape `(batch_size, ) + variable_shape`, that is, you now have per-batch-element gradients. You can now manipulate these gradients however you want, and should at some point get rid of the additional batch axis of course (e.g. averaging). That is, `new_grad` should have the same shape as the corresponding variable.

Regarding your last comment: As I mentioned, the loss function indeed needs to return one loss per data point, i.e. must not average over the batch. However, this is not enough because if you were to give this vector to `tape.gradient`, the gradient function will simply sum up the loss values (since it only works with scalars). This is why `jacobian` is necessary.

Finally, `jacobian` can be very slow. In the worst case, run time may be multiplied by batch size because it needs to compute that many separate gradients. However, this is done in parallel to some degree so the slowdown might not be as bad.

Comment: Thank you this is great, this is pretty much what I had in mind. I tried this and I am getting this error on the `fit` line now. I ran into this yesterday and was looking it up but could not figure out what the problem is. I am TF version 2.2.0. The error is: `UnrecognizedFlagError: Unknown command line flag 'f'`.

Comment: Seems to be a bug that can be fixed by changing the version. I'm gonna try.

Comment: OK Got it, thank you! Yes I upgraded to nightly ( 2.5.~ ) and was able to to reproduce what I was seeing with my first version of working code using `K.mean` over the batch axis.